# How to buy weapon?

Tags: android, hitman-sniper

It's unlocked, but the buy button is disabled (grey). How can I buy it?

Is it because I don't have enough money?

[image: Image of Buy screen]

Answer (score 1):

The weapon in question is an in-app purchase, which you'd have to spend real money on (though showing a cost of 0).

[image: Largo Weapon, "Buy Weapon | GBP 0"]

When you click on the Buy Weapon, it brings up the standard Purchase dialog:

[image: Android In-App Purchase Dialog]

When the Android device is not connected to a network (tested in Airplane Mode), the Buy button becomes greyed-out and identical to your original screenshot.

To buy the weapon (assuming that you want to spend real money), you will need to connect your device to the internet while you play.